# AutoHotKey I can't make the script work properly (sending text) - Answered

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to make a script that makes me: press enter > write this text/code [&AvT2LQEA] > then press enter again. It's for ingame purpose of showing off specific item.

So far I've tried to make it myself but it always misses the first [ and I'm ending up with sending only &AvT2LQEA] and the game won't recognize this code.

```
   1::
   SendInput {Enter up}
   SendInput {Enter down}
   Send [&AvT2LQEA]
   SendInput {Enter up}
   SendInput {Enter down}
   return

   q::
   ExitApp
```

Thanks to 3D1T0R the problem got solved.
I had to:
         1. swap {Enter up} and {Enter down}
         2. add Sleep before text - the game chat couldn't keep up with script

In the meantime, I figured out that making a script that paste already copied text works without lag/fps issues in the game and I could delete the Sleep.

I ended up with this scrpit that works perfectly for me

```
   1::
   SendInput {Enter down}
   SendInput {Enter up}
   Send, ^{vk56}
   SendInput {Enter down}
   SendInput {Enter up}
   return

   q::
   ExitApp
```

Comment: Turns out I had to add Sleep, 100 before sending text because it worked too fast for the game

Comment: Also, you probably want to swap your `{Enter up}` and `{Enter down}` in both places you used them.

Comment: Sorry, [apparently](//superuser.com/help/self-answer) you have to wait 48 hours to be able to accept your own answer (so that others have a chance to give answers which you [in two days] may decide are better).

Comment: Also, solutions shouldn't be in the question. Instead you should mention your changes, explanations, and/or alternate solution(s) in your answer post.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is

```
1::
SendInput {Enter down}
SendInput {Enter up}

Sleep, 100
Send, [&AvT2LQEA]

SendInput {Enter down}
SendInput {Enter up}
return

q::
ExitApp
```